# Getting single result of type int in hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have a controller that communicates with my service to get the id of the logged in user. I first get the username using principal object

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/lid",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Integer lid(Principal p) {
        String name = p.getName();
        Integer gotid = personService.getDbId(name);
        return gotid;   

}
```

then call the service passing the username to the dao

```
public Integer getDbId(String name){
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Query theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("select id from app_user where sso_id=:name");
        //set multiple parameters from the user
        //theQuery.setParameter("city", city);
        theQuery.setParameter("sso_id", name);
        //Get the int or the big int
        //Get results into list object : List list = query.list();
        int theid = (int)theQuery.getSingleResult();
        //uniqueResult
        return theid;
        //org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: from near line 1, column 8 [select from app_user where sso_id=:name]
    }
```

However, i get this error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: app_user is not
>   mapped [select id from app_user where sso_id=:name]

How can i fix it to give me the one result that i want?.

Comment: Your query seems to me incorrect. What would you like to select from the database (Which column)?  select something from app_user where sso_id=:name

Comment: I have updated the query and the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to execute pure SQL but hibernate expects HQL. So it tries to find an Entity with `app_user` name but fails - there is no such class.

Try instead

```
Query theQuery = currentSession.createSQLQuery("...");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
Query theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("select id from AppUser where ssoId=:name");
```

AppUser might be your class name and ssoId is field name.

use your Domain class name and domain field names whatever it is because query requires HQL.